# EF 5, one to many, more than one table

Tags: collections, entity-framework-5, one-to-many

I'm having a little of trouble with the following classes:

```
public class TwoVariableDetails
{
    public TwoVariableDetails()
    {    
        MovementsPerBlocks = new HashSet<MovementsRow>();
        MovementsPerShiftTypes = new HashSet<MovementsRow>();
        MovementsPerMachines = new HashSet<MovementsRow>();
        MovementsPerShifts = new HashSet<MovementsRow>();
    }

    [Key]
    public Guid TwoVariableDetailsId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(1000)]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }        

    public virtual ICollection<MovementsRow> MovementsPerBlocks { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MovementsRow> MovementsPerShiftTypes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MovementsRow> MovementsPerMachines { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MovementsRow> MovementsPerShifts { get; set; }      

}

[Table("Movement")]
public class MovementsRow
{
    public MovementsRow()
    {
        MovementsCells = new HashSet<MovementsCell>();
    }
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [CsvField(Ignore = true)]
    public Guid MovementId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int RowNo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [CsvField(Ignore = true)]
    public Guid ModelId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ModelId")]
    [CsvField(Ignore = true)]
    public virtual TwoVariableDetails Model { get; set; }

    [TypeConverter(typeof(MovementsCellTypeConverter))]
    public virtual ICollection<MovementsCell> MovementsCells { get; set; }

}

[Table("MovementCell")]
public class MovementsCell
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [CsvField(Ignore = true)]
    public Guid CellId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ColumnNo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Count { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [CsvField(Ignore = true)]
    public Guid MovementId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MovementId")]
    [CsvField(Ignore = true)]
    public virtual MovementsRow Model { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to save it to the database I get the following error:

```
    The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Movement_dbo.TwoVariableDetails_ModelId". The conflict occurred in database "aspnet-GreenCranes.UI-20130516", table "dbo.TwoVariableDetails", column 'TwoVariableDetailsId'.
```

The statement has been terminated.

This is the code I'm using for saving:

```
twoVariableDetails.TwoVariableDetailsId = Guid.NewGuid();
_context.TwoVariableDetailsModels.Add(twoVariableDetails);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

My table looks like this:

```
Movement
    - Column    
        - MovementId
        - RowNo
        - ModelId(FK, uniqueidentifier, not null)
        - TwoVariableDetails_TwoVariableDetailsId(FK, uniqueidentifier, null)
        - TwoVariableDetails_TwoVariableDetailsId2(FK, uniqueidentifier, null)
        - TwoVariableDetails_TwoVariableDetailsId3(FK, uniqueidentifier, null)
        - TwoVariableDetails_TwoVariableDetailsId4(FK, uniqueidentifier, null)
    - Keys
        - FK_dbo.Movement_dbo.TwoVariableDetails_ModelId
        - FK_dbo.Movement_dbo.TwoVariableDetails_TwoVariableDetails_TwoVariableDetailsId
        - FK_dbo.Movement_dbo.TwoVariableDetails_TwoVariableDetails_TwoVariableDetailsId1
        - FK_dbo.Movement_dbo.TwoVariableDetails_TwoVariableDetails_TwoVariableDetailsId2
        - FK_dbo.Movement_dbo.TwoVariableDetails_TwoVariableDetails_TwoVariableDetailsId3
```

I'm not sure what is the problem with my approach. Should I change the MovementsRow class to have four Model properties and four modelid fk and then use InverseProperty attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MovementsRow.Model` belongs to another relationship than the four collections in `TwoVariableDetails`. That's the reason why you don't have four, but five foreign keys in the database table. When you insert `twoVariableDetails` into the DB and it contains a `MovementRow` instance in one of the collections EF expects that its `ModelId` is set to a Guid that references an existing `TwoVariableDetails` row - which it doesn't apparently. Hence the exception.

> Should I change the MovementsRow class to have four Model properties
>   and four modelid fk and then use InverseProperty attribute?

I'd say yes. It's probably the best solution. The alternative is to have no `Model` property at all in `MovementRow`. It's working but you would not be able to navigate from `MovementRow` to `TwoVariableDetails` then.

Answer (score 0):

Your `FK_dbo.Movement_dbo.TwoVariableDetails_ModelId` is being violated, simply put - the `ModelId` that the `Movement` record is using doesn't yet exist in `TwoVariableDetails`.

If you wanted to keep it simple, and transactional, then you could use [`TransactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) along with your database context, save the `TwoVariableDetails` first in the transaction, and then the records that relate back to it:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
using (var tranScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required) {
  // don't save the Movement records yet
  twoVariableDetails.TwoVariableDetailsId = Guid.NewGuid();
  _context.TwoVariableDetailsModels.Add(twoVariableDetails);
  _context.SaveChanges();

 // now create the movement records, add them to twoVariableDetails
  ...
  _context.SaveChanges();

 // commit the transaction
 scope.Complete();
}
```